# TikZ: Coordinate on shape vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tikz-shape

I know that I can draw a rectangle with tikz using `\draw (0.0,0.0) rectangle (1.0,1.0);`. Is there a possibility to determine all 4 edge coordinates directly from the shape?

I do can save the lower left coordinate and the upper right by `\draw (0.0,0.0) coordinate (lb) rectangle (1.0,1.0) coordinate (ru);`. But is there a way to get the upper left and bottom right corner directly from the shape?

I know I can calculate them. But are they directly accessible from the shape?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% the rectangle
\draw (0.0,0.0) coordinate (lb) rectangle (1.0,1.0) coordinate (ru);

% coordinates
\draw (lb) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw (ru) circle [radius=2pt];

% calculated coordinates
\draw[dashed] (lb |- ru) coordinate (lu) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw[dashed] (lb -| ru) coordinate (rb) circle [radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own rectangle path. In the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my rectangle/.style={to path={
-| coordinate[pos=0.5] (#1-2) (\tikztotarget) coordinate (#1-3) 
-| coordinate (#1-4) (\tikztostart) coordinate (#1-1) }}]
\draw (0,0) edge[my rectangle=krtek] (1,1);
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw (krtek-\X) circle [radius=2pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the style `my rectangle=<coordinate base name>` will give the four corners the names `coordinate base name-1`, ... , `coordinate base name-4`.

[image]

And there are, of course, predefined shapes that have the corner coordinates stored in anchors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% the rectangle
\path (0,0) node[draw,anchor=south west,minimum size=1cm] (R) {};
\foreach \X in {45,135,225,315}
{\draw (R.\X) circle [radius=2pt];}

\path (2,0) node[draw,anchor=south west,minimum size={sqrt(2)*1cm},regular polygon,regular
polygon sides=4] (poly) {};

\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw (poly.corner \X) circle [radius=2pt];}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to explicitely declare coordinates for the corners, you can automatically convert your rectangle into a `node` with `fit` library. This way, the resultant node gives you all rectangular anchors without havint to name them.

Following example shows how to insert rectangular coordinates into `fit` parameter. The result node is equivalent to previously drawn rectangle (you don't need to draw the previous rectangle, it's just for demonstration purposes).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\node[fit={(0,0) (2,1)}, inner sep=0pt, draw=red, opacity=.5] (a) {};

\foreach \i in {north east, north west, south east, south west}
    \draw (a.\i) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]